# How do I answer "Where do you work?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What are **the main purposes** to ask someone 'Where do you work?' apart from to find out the type of place he or she works in?

I can answer:

> I work in a shop.
>   I work in a hospital.
>   I work in an office.

But what other things can (or should) I use as a reply to this question?

---

#### Extra question:

sometimes I see

> I work **at** a shop. 
>   I work **at** a hospital. 
>   I work **at** an office.

What's the difference between 'at' and 'in' in this case?

Comment: There is very little difference in this context. But your question asks about *the main purposes* behind asking somebody where they work. That doesn't seem to have much to do with your at/in question, so I'm a bit confused about what you're actually asking.

Comment: @Kevin Workman I mean: do I need to say the name of the company or the city where I work answering this question? Or only type of plece.

Comment: It completely depends on the context of the situation. If somebody from the same company asks you where you work, they probably want to know which *department* you work in, not which city. If somebody from another country asks you where you work, they probably want to know which city as well. There is not a single catch-all answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from an American-culture perspective, instead of a purely grammatical perspective, when someone asks you where you work, they are trying to get to know you. It's an invitation to open up and tell them about yourself. If you say something short like "I work at a hospital" and leave it at that, you are telling them that you don't really want to talk to them.

Of course this all depends on context. It's possible that they just want directions to your place of business.

edit: To answer the second part of your question:

You can say "I work at a hospital" and "I work in a hospital". Both are equally correct.

You can say "I work at McDonalds", but it's incorrect to say "I work in McDonalds".

You can say "I work in New York City", but it's incorrect to say "I work at New York City".

You can say "I work in medicine" but you can't say "I work at medicine".

Comment: I agree with the others but why can't McD's employees say "I work in McDonalds"?

Answer (score 3):

Typically when somebody asks where you work, they want to know what company you're working for. You'd answer with the name of that company, not just the type of place. If you worked at a hospital and answered somebody asking you that question with

> I work at a hospital.

Most likely they'd follow up with "Which hospital?", since just working "at a hospital" doesn't really tell them much. So tell them the specific place, for example,

> I work at Mount Sinai (Hospital).

If you don't work at a particular place, say, if you're a contractor or self-employed, then answer with that instead, because there is no "where".

Answer (score 1):

Using at or in depends on the place in which work. If you are part of a government, you can say I work in a government service. If it is a small shop, I would prefer, I work at a shop.

Comment: my textbook says: 'in a shop', 'in an office', 'in a lab'. Are they wrong?

Comment: Your textbook? Are you trying to learn a specific way of saying this?

Comment: @Joe Z. I just want to see the difference.