# Which one is correct? I am working in a bank or I am working at a bank

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct? Am I working *in* or *at* a bank?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I answer "Where do you work?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161225/how-do-i-answer-where-do-you-work) with duplicates at [I work _at_ a registrar's office or _in_ a registrar's office?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268630/i-work-at-registrars-office-or-in-registrars-office), etc.

Comment: Depends on context.